# How are analytic continuations computed?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Suppose I define some analytic function on some domain $\Omega_1$ and I want to extend this function to the unique analytic continuation on $\Omega_2$. Are there any general methods of computing the unique analytic continuation? Is the analytic continuation more nuanced than say replacing the $x$ with a $z$ if $\Omega_1 = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The two common strategies I'm familiar with: you find a new expression for the same function, but this expression is analytic on a larger domain. This is typically an integral of some kind. Another strategy: you patch multiple discs together, using power series convergent on each individual disc, to get a new function defined on a larger domain.

Comment: Another strategy: Suppose your function $f$ satisfies the equation $f'=g$, where $g$ is holomorphic on $\Omega_2$. Then compute the extension by integrating $g$ alongs paths in $\Omega_2$.